# Backbone save/fetch VS DAO?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Just wanted to know why on backend applications we use a DAO pattern and on single pages applications with frameworks like Backbone we use save/fetch functions on the backbone models/collections.

I've already seen this for server-side developpment with frameworks like Play (Java/Scala) and i think Rails do the same (?). In my opinion that's a cool feature for small projects but not really suitable for large applications.

I just wonder why when search "backbone + dao" the only usecases i find are about browser localStorage and not about accessing remote datas. Am i the only one to think a complex backbone app should perhaps use the DAO pattern to access remote data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Backbone is largely modeled after Ruby on Rails when it comes to data access, which bakes the Active Record (AR) pattern directly in to it. It's the preference of most Rails developers, and it's the preference of Backbone's core team, but it's not the only valid way to do things.

FWIW, I only use Backbone's AR style methods around 10 to 20 percent of the time. In the vast majority of cases, I use either a separate DAO or a command-pattern style of persistence, facilitated by [AmplifyJS](http://amplifyjs.com/api/request/).

Comment: care to elaborate on the latter? Examples? Is there a link for any article on your blog?

Comment: thanks, will check that. Can you explain how AmpliofyJS can be integrated in a backbone app?

Comment: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/05/04/wrapping-ajax-in-a-thin-command-framework-for-backbone-apps/ - this blog post was written with a home-grown command framework, but if you replace that with Amplify's "Request" framework, it's exactly what I'm talking about.

Comment: Derick,though I have been reading your articles and found useful and trying to implement code in backbone, lately i started looking back on KO or other stuff.The reason I am not from ruby world and sometimes find things not really clearly sliced as I expect.maybe i have wrong impression however mainly I mean single responsibility issue.for instance I had seen KO developers could use DAO, repository patterns using some third party libs. In particular ocassion would it be ok to treat backbone collections as sort of repositories?  do you have any sample code where you have used amplify.js? thanks